# Replace value on index in array

Tags: swift

I have a array:

```
[h,e,l,l,o]
```

And i want to replace an value on the index, for example i want to change the first l at index 2. I know the index so that is not a problem, the only problem is to replace that value.

How can i do this?

Comment: What did you tried? Post your approach here and we can give answer you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the `insert` function will add a new value to the array, what you need to do is simply

```
var newCharacter = "a"

arr[2] = newCharacter
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

You can modify your array like that:

```
var array = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
array[2] = "Six eggs"
```

---